# Minitest instance variables logged but assertion gets nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

A minitest returns `Expected nil to be truthy.`

The controller action processes the following statements

```
@cu = current_user.roleshopusers.where(shop_id: @site.shop_id).first
@cu_role = @cu.try(:role_id)
@cu_buyer = @cu.buyer
Rails.logger.info @cu.inspect
Rails.logger.info @cu.buyer
```

And the test log returns:

```
#<Roleshopuser id: 434940726, user_id: 7, shop_id: 31, role_id: 1, buyer: true, special_support: false, special_needs: nil, notes: nil, discount: 0.0, created_at: "2021-06-16 13:56:37.288691000 +0200", updated_at: "2021-06-16 13:56:37.288691000 +0200">
true
```

but the test, while returning correct values with the same method definition,

```
puts current_user.id
puts current_user.roleshopusers.where(shop_id: @site.shop_id).first.buyer
puts @cu.inspect
    assert @cu_buyer
```

has no instance variable available to it.

```
7
true
nil
```

How should this test be stated, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance variables are not globals. They are lexical variables scoped to the instance where the are defined. This is a common beginner hangup if you start with Rails without learning Ruby first as it "magically" makes your controller instance variables available to the view.

Your expectation that the instance variable you have defined in your controller should be set in the test is thus completely false as they are completely separate instances of different classes.

In legacy controller tests the `assigns` method was commonly used to poke inside of the controller and write assertions about its instance variables:

```
assert(assigns(:cu_buyer))
```

This was deprechiated and removed entirely from Rails, but still [exists as an gem](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing). Its use is not recommended outside of legacy code. Instead the modern approach is to write integration tests that [test the response and effects of your controller without poking into its internals](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950).

Comment: Very helpful explanation.  While I understand the reasoning in the change, and in most instances testing the view will effect that test, this particular method is a refactor and assigned to the application_controller. So, to test this refactoring, what woul dbe a better solution to the gem: have/create a view where this instance variable is available?

Comment: I really have no idea since I don't know what behavior this is supposed to test or what  "testing the view will effect that test" is even supposed to mean. You test controllers through integration or system tests which drive the whole stack and then write assertions about the result - thats the modern way. Views can be tested in isolation through view tests but they are not used that often as you can cover the key paths through the application with system tests.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers